# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting not right sometimes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a google sheet to track some payments and have created some conditional formatting rules to show when there is under/over/correct payments. It seems to work correctly, except for one set. I am linking to a spreadsheet so hopefully you can view it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IJ6zFXP2cMRQmbf3KSFEcO_H36CP3sBwp1dfvJMSDmc/edit?usp=sharing

It seems to go wrong on one particular set...line 19 shows that 26 cents is still owed - it shows correct. If you then look at line 14 (it works upwards), the Still Owed shows as $0.00 and not $ - and it shows in red and not white. And from then and upward, even though nothing is owed, it doesn't show right. However, I tried on line 15 making it show a penny is owed, and then line 10, it was paid off and so is $0 owed and it shows right.

I've tried copying the formatting and checking all the columns and I think they all look the same.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: This is probably a floating point problem.
change: =SUM(F4-G4+K4-L4+P4-Q4)  to =ROUND(SUM(F4-G4+K4-L4+P4-Q4),2)

Comment: Thanks! The Round worked...I thought I even tried that...guess not. So weird that it only seemed to affect that one line...

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Custom formula** in Conditional Formatting.

Note: Use VALUE() in Format rules helps you to shorten the content **Apply to range**, because that ignores text cells

[image]

Comment: thank you. that is a good way to apply it to all with ignoring text.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a (lack of rounding up/down) issue.

I changed the formula in S14 from:

```
=SUM(F14-G14+K14-L14+P14-Q14)
```

to:

```
=round(SUM(F14-G14+K14-L14+P14-Q14),2)
```

This way it will disregard any decimals beyond the second and thus make    $ 0,00    truly 0.